# Reading child of an automated unique ID in a nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

**How do I get data of a child of an automated unique ID in a nested ng-repeat, if the ID is not in the first level?**

My firebase data set is structured as such (note: I do not know the amount or values of users, dates or unique IDs in that data set):

```
John:[

      10-12-2015: {

          "-JcFXid1A2G8EM7A_kwc": {
             "description" : "hi",
             "timestamp": "1449751857810"},

          "-JcFZP5FNtL4Yj6nja_7": {
             "description" : "this",
             "timestamp": "144975185345"},
      },

      11-12-2015: {

          "-JcFtGoZL7J-CCIjTYcL": {
             "description" : "is",
             "timestamp": "14497518513715"},

          "-JcFXid1A2G8EM7A_kwc": {
             "description" : "me",
             "timestamp": "1449751846956"},
      },

]

Thomas: [ ... ]
```

My HTML code is:

```
<ion-list>
    <ul class="list">

        <li ng-repeat="day in list">
            <ion-item class="item-divider">{{day.$id}}</ion-item>
            // That works as my output is "10-12-2015, etc"

            <li ng-repeat="key in day">
            // This does not work
                <ion-item>{{key.description}}</ion-item>
            </li>

        </li>

    </ul>
</ion-list>
```

I am new to Firebase and Angular so my apologies if I am missing something obvious. I also understand that Firebase recommends flat hierarchies, but sorting it by user and date is important for data analysis I need to do. But I would be open to suggestions.

FYI - My controller looks like this:

```
.controller('summaryCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$firebase','$firebaseArray','SessionData', '$ionicPopup', function($scope,$state,$firebase,$firebaseArray,SessionData,$ionicPopup){

var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://id.firebaseio.com/" + userid);
  var fbArray = $firebaseArray(firebaseObj);

  fbArray.$loaded()
  .then(function(){
      $scope.list = fbArray;
  })
}])
```

Thanks.

Comment: it doesnt work because in
    <li ng-repeat="key in day"> day isn't an array, it's an object.
try to do something like  ng-repeat="(key, value) in day">

Comment: @cesarandavisa hmm, I thought since _day_ is part of the array _list_ it would be an array itself. Any other ideas on how to change _day_ into an array? Your suggestion did not work if I implement it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `.$loaded()`, the `$firebaseArray` will take care of triggering `$digest` when the data is loaded. The `.$loaded()` promise is useful for resolving in routes.

In your case though you need to go down into the `day` key to create the array. Try a data structure like below:

```
{
  "userMessages": {
    "$uid": {
       "$message_id": { 
         "timestamp": 1450048003760 // use a timestamp
       }
     }
  }
}
```

This way you can get messages per user by: `/userMessages/$uid/`. Then using a query you can get them by date.

You can create factory to simplify this.

Don't mind the code structure below, it uses the [Angular Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
  .service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
  .factory('messages', Messages)
  .controller('SummaryCtrl', SummaryCtrl);

function Messages(rootRef, $firebaseArray) {
  return function Messages(userid, date) {
    // turn the date into a timestamp
    var timestamp = date.getTime();
    var messagesRef = rootRef.child('userMessages').child(userid);
    // query for messages on that day
    var query = messagesRef.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(timestamp);
    return $firebaseArray(query);
  };
}

function SummaryCtrl($scope, messages, rootRef) {
  var user = rootRef.getUser()
  var today = new Date();
  $scope.messages = messages(user.uid, today);
}
```

Comment: Thank you David. I should have clarified but I do not know the amounts or values of _day_ (e.g. '10-12-2015') or users and unique IDs for that matter. Any suggestions on how I could solve this?

Comment: Can you provide more context do your data structure?

Comment: The idea is the following: Every day a user can make one or many entries. Some days a user does not make any entries, some days one, some days more then one.

Comment: I want to group all messages of a user on a per date basis. I figured the best way was to store each new message to https://id.firebaseio.com/items/{user}/{date} where they get the unique upload ID. (So far I have not worked with user ID but I will look into that.)

I would be open for a flatter data structure but am not sure how I can list of unique dates if they are just attributes of each message.

I hope this is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I updated my answer to use queries and a new data structure.

Comment: David, thank you again for your reply. I already had my data structured as you suggested. If I understand correctly your code gives me all messages before (and potentially after) a certain date. Since I want all messages, I cannot look for specific dates. I would like one array with all messages grouped by all dates, instead of individual arrays for each day. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I had posted the wrong data structure. There's no need to key off of the `day` when can do a query. Take a look at the updated structure. The query returns all of the messages on that day. If you don't query it will return all of the messages.

Comment: Hi David. Sorry for the long silence. Your post did help. Thank you very much!